# How to insert multiple elements in array in c program?

Tags: c

I can insert an element in an array but I want to know that is this possible to insert multiple(two or three..) element in an array by using c program. I tried a little, there is no problem or eror but it doesn't work.

Here is my code which I had tried to make a program which can insert multiple element in array:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    
    int size,i;
    
    printf("Enter array length - ");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    
    int array[size];

    printf("Enter array elements : \n");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }    

    int el_no; //el_no means elemnet no which user should input
    printf("How many element you want to insert - ");
    scanf("%d",&el_no);

    int element[el_no];

    printf("Element value - ");
    for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
     scanf("%d",&element[i]);  
    }
    int index[el_no];

    printf("Index no - ");
    for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
    scanf("%d",&index);   
    }

    for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
        for(i=index[i]; i< size+el_no;i++){
            array[i+1]=array[i];
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<el_no; i++){
        array[index[i]]=element[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i<size+el_no; i++){
        printf("%d\t",array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "there is no problem or eror but it doesn't work" that sounds like a problem. What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What are you giving as input? What is it outputting? What do you expect it to output?

Comment: In your `for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){` loop, `scanf("%d",&index);` -> `scanf("%d",&index[i]);`

Comment: i want to insert two element in array. It takes those inputs but the program sudden stop after  this line------  printf("Index no - ");
    for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
    scanf("%d",&index);   
    }----
it doesn't insert element or print the array. can you please tell me how can I insert multiple element in array???

Comment: You don't have space to insert the elements.  Attempting to write to `array[i]` for `i >= size` is undefined behavior.

Comment: but i write array[i] for i <= size
Can you give me the code about how to insert multiple elements in array using c??

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you want (at least, not directly).  Once you say

```
int array[size];
```

that array can only hold `size` number of elements, no more.

Your program first stores values into `array[0]`, `array[1]`, ..., up to `array[size-1]`.  That's perfectly fine.

But then when you say

```
for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
    for(i=index[i]; i< size+el_no;i++){
        array[i+1]=array[i];
    }
}
```

you are trying to move some of the array's elements over (to make room for new ones), but you're moving them *outside the array*, which is never going to work.

One fix (not quite what you want) would be to declare the array bigger than it needs to be.  For example, you could say

```
int array[size+5];
```

and then later double-check that it will be big enough:

```
printf("How many element you want to insert - ");
scanf("%d",&el_no);
if(el_no > 5) {
    printf("sorry, I can't insert that many\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

The "better" way, although it gets into pointers and dynamic memory allocation perhaps sooner than you're ready to, would be to use a pointer simulating an array, using `malloc` to allocate space for it to point to:

```
int *array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Than, later, you can resize it:

```
array = realloc(array, (size + el_no) * sizeof(int));
```

This is just an example -- in reality, you'd need to check the return values of `malloc` and `realloc` to make sure they're not NULL, indicating that something has gone wrong.

Also there are some other problems with your code.  The way you're using the auxiliary `index` array looks wrong, and probably isn't necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to show in my comment, you're not specifying an index for the `index` array. In that loop, you're `scanf`ing to `&index`, which is the wrong argument for `scanf`.  Your compiler should be giving you a warning:

```
    warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'int (*)[el_no]' [-Wformat=]
   32 |     scanf("%d",&index);
      |            ~^  ~~~~~~
      |             |  |
      |             |  int (*)[el_no]
      |             int *
```

Despite the warning, what's most likely happening is each value you enter in the loop is getting stored at `index[0]`.  You need to change that loop from

```
for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
    scanf("%d",&index);   
}
```

to

```
for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
    scanf("%d",&index[i]); // <-- note the [i] addition
}
```

You've done this correctly in the previous loop

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
}
```

This may not be the only problem, but it's *a* problem, and too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the code and stated where to correct the faults

#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

Initialize j here

```
int size,i,j;

printf("Enter array length - ");
scanf("%d",&size);

int array[size];

printf("Enter array elements : \n");
for(i=0; i<size; i++){
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
}

int el_no; //el_no means elemnet no which user should input
printf("How many element you want to insert - ");
scanf("%d",&el_no);

int element[el_no];

printf("Element value - ");
for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
 scanf("%d",&element[i]);
}
int index[el_no];

printf("Index no - ");
```

here is a mistake you can correct

```
for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
scanf("%d",&index[i]);//Add[i] here
}
```

Also do not use same variable in more than one for loop in a nested loop

```
for(i=0; i<el_no;i++){
    for(j=index[i]; j< size+el_no;j++){//Use any other variable than 'i' in this for loop
```

depending on what you want to do you can correct this line below

```
        array[i+1]=array[i];
    }
}
for(i=0; i<el_no; i++){
    array[index[i]]=element[i];
}
for(i=0; i<size+el_no; i++){
    printf("%d\t",array[i]);
}
return 0;
```

}

All is good.
Hope you find it useful.